# How to configure Unicorn when using Nginx virtual hosts

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean) to create a Rails app on my server with Nginx and Unicorn.

Now I'm trying to run two Rails apps on the same server. My first app works fine when I set `working_directory "/path/to/app1"` in `/etc/unicorn.conf`, however when going to the domain for the second app my first app shows up. I've already set up my virtual host configuration for both apps in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and symlinked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. How can I configure Unicorn so that it recognises the second app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Unicorn can only run one Rails app per instance, so multiple daemons need to be run per app.